# PM2 clustering, WebSockets, Nodejs(express) how to implement shared data(variable)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, websocket, pm2

I am writing real time connection web server with WebSocket(ws) library in Node js(Express) where i an saving users in a variable clients to be able to find the right ws user to send data. The clients variable is array of objects. At the end i am going to connect PM2 clustering and i need to share all the clients between all worker and master processes, i was thinking to use mongodb to save data but i am doing alot of data modification which may lead to slow down the server very often data update.

Is there any way to make share data between pm2 clusters faster to work with and more consistent. I need very often access Clients variable and update it very fast to have persistent data between all clusters.

Thank you very much.

Comment: you have any solution regarding the same ?.

Comment: Yes, i had this problem with having shared state between different clusters and servers so i went with writing a library which manages it for you. You can check it here: https://github.com/ClusterWS/ClusterWS

Answer (score 1):

You have put an incredible amount of factors into your question and you really have to divide them up to correctly understand the processes involved.

1. Your DB which should be your first consideration. Whether you are going to use PM2 or not if you are going to do CRUD and especially UPDATE that is always going to take resources. Even if you use MySQL. Update on data takes resources if you are updating the data in a DB and not just in a memory space. (Redis or MemCached).

So you would need to take into account exactly what updates are being done, how often and exactly how you are doing it.

You also need to plan your space both for the DB and how much memory you have allocated. For instance Mongodb is notorious for grabbing memory.

2. Now once you have decided on your DB turn to master-worker. There first look at what the DB offers and how to implement it safely and efficiently. (mongodb has excellent docs on this).
3. Now you come to clusters. I love PM2 but that too has to be set up correctly. There seems to be this idea that to implement a cluster you just need to throw PM2 into 
   the mix and voila you have a cluster which works. Nothing could be further from the truth. Your PM2 file (whatever format you want to use) must be set up and fine tuned). Grabbing all the cores may or may not be the best in your situation. Again this has to deal with your data and CRUD operations.
4. Finally you threw "persistence" into the match. This is a function of so many factors - but essentially it goes back to the way you have set up your data, master - workers AND of course your sharding (If  any) and where your servers are physically and if they are working with duplication or not.

Simply put you threw every possible term into your question which will not be solved simply by throwing PM2 into the mix,  and I use PM2 all the time. PM2 is not a magic bullet. It is one tool on the arsenal.